# Entity Framework - Oracle - Compare nullable DateTime using linq is not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework with Oracle and I'm trying to do a query using linq comparing a nullable DateTime, but when I do this comparation, the query gives me wrong result.

I execute the equivalent query in PL/SQL Developer and I have the correct result.

Here is my code

```
using (var context = new CorporativoContext())
        {
            context.Database.Log = Console.Write;

            var parametro = (from p in context.PARAMETRO
                    join pv in context.PARAMETRO_VALOR on p.Id equals pv.Id
                    where p.Descricao == descricaoParametro && pv.InicioVigencia <= DateTime.Now && pv.FimVigencia == null
                    select pv).FirstOrDefault();

            return parametro;
        }
```

the property"FimVigencia" is nullable DateTime (DateTime? FimVigencia) and when I compare it to null, the query result returns nothing, but if I remove this comparation, the query gives me an object with null value for property "FimVigencia".

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How about `HasValue` ?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I tried, but not worked. A colleague gives me the solution. I shared in answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I will post here for anyone who have same problem

I need to use DbFunctions.TruncateTime to compare to null

here is my code:

```
(from p in _context.PARAMETRO
                join pv in _context.PARAMETRO_VALOR on p.Id equals pv.Id
                where p.Descricao == descricaoParametro && pv.InicioVigencia <= DateTime.Now && 
                (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(pv.FimVigencia) == null || pv.FimVigencia >= DateTime.Now)
                select pv).FirstOrDefault();
```